# Count rows where date within a year and customer equals to

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to make a formula that can give me the count of rows where one column is within a year, and another column is a specific customer?

[image]

Comment: [`COUNTIFS()`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) should do the job. If you're working with an older version of Excel, you can use [`SUMPRODUCT()`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) instead.

Comment: Easy way would be adding an extra column with a formula that returns the year of your `Dato` and then use that column as criteria range in your COUNTIFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sample formula given below to achieve the desired result.

> =COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$22,">="&DATE($F$2,1,1),$B$3:$B$22,"<"&DATE($F$2+1,1,1),$C$3:$C$22,$E5)

**Formula Contents:**

B3:B22 = a Range of data contains Dates

C3:C22 = a range of data contains Customer names

F2 = Year (Your Input)

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screen Shot Image]

You can change the range and formula according to your requirements. I hope this helps.